# Xamarin Studio purchase

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio, xamarin.mac

I am planing to develop the cross platform mobile application in iOS and android in Xamarin.

I have question related to pricing.

My development IDE will be Xamrine studio in mac system
I have few Question : https://store.xamarin.com/

Question 1 ) Can I develop my application by using Xamarin Studio Community FREE

Question 2) Xamarin Studio Community FREE  is only for 30 Days or it is for Life Time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Question 1 ) Can I develop my application by using Xamarin Studio Community FREE

**Answer** : Yes ,you can develop mobile application using Xamarin Studio Community Edition.

Question 2) Xamarin Studio Community FREE is only for 30 Days or it is for Life Time ?

**Answer**:Its free(i.e. its not 30 day trial version) for Students, open-source projects,and non-enterprise up to 5 users.

Answer (score 1):

You have to carefully read the [License Conditions for VS Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/license-terms/mt171547/).

- 1.1 Says, you can use it, if you are an individual.
- 1.2 Provides the rules that apply to organizations, which includes some rescrictions.

Xamarin is free as of March 2015 and you can use it for free together with VS Community or Xamarin Studio, if the above conditions apply to you.